# Nginx - Allowing origin IP

Tags: nginx, proxy, whitelist

Nginx supports `allow` and `deny` syntax to restrict IPs, e.g. `allow 192.168.1.1;`. But if traffic goes through a reverse proxy, the IP will refer to the proxy's IP. So how can it be configured to whitelist a specific origin IP and deny all other incoming requests?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

remote_addr will refer to the proxy, but you can configure the proxy to send the client address with header fields X-Real-IP/X-Forwarded-For.

Combined with the [ngx_http_realip](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html) module, you can modify the incoming header to use the real client address for remote_addr. I believe this will work as expected with allow/deny syntax.

Just to clarify -- allow/deny syntax should be identical after enabling and configuring the module. Substitute your IP and your proxy addresses below.

Back-end nginx allow/deny:

```
location / {
    allow <your ip>;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny  all;
}
```

Back-end nginx realip configuration:

```
set_real_ip_from  <your proxy>;
real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
```

On your nginx proxy configuration:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

If you have multiple intermediate proxies involved, you'll need to enable real_ip_recursive and whitelist additional addresses with the set_real_ip_from directive.

Comment: Thanks - could you show how the config would look for this, as the module page only shows how to get the variable but doesn't show how to whitelist.

Comment: I see, it replaces the proxy IP with the origin IP. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that mess of a comment. Updated my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working with the following configuration, using the `http_geo` module:

```
geo $remote_addr $give_access {
    proxy 172.0.0.0/8; # <-- Private IP range here
    default 0;
    11.22.33.44 1; # <-- Allowed IP here
}


server {

    # more config ... 

    location ^~ /secure_url_here {
        if ($give_access = 0) {
          return 403; 
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; # <-- Your directive here
    }
}
```

Ref: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html