# Kubernetes ingress-nginx redirection based on IP

Tags: amazon-eks, ingress-nginx

I would like to redirect traffic from any other user apart from my static Public IP  to get redirected to a maintenance page ,i have deployed the ingress-nginx in an aws eks cluster,

How do i achieve this?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: ex
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      more_set_headers "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN";
      more_set_headers "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block";
      more_set_headers "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff";
      more_set_headers "Allow: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT";
      more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT";
      more_set_headers "X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none";
      more_set_headers "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *";
      more_set_headers "Content-Security-Policy: frame-src *;";
      more_set_headers "Referrer-Policy: same-origin";
      more_set_headers "Permissions-Policy: accelerometer=(), camera=(), geolocation=(), gyroscope=(), magnetometer=(), microphone=(), payment=(), usb=()";
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/eventsource: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 500m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "4000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "4000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "4000"

  name: kubernetes-ingress
  namespace: default

spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: svc
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

Comment: It looks like there are no solutions using nginx-ingress only. Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76809233/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-different-url-based-on-the-source-ips-in-nginx-ingress-c